# (not an experienced coder) how do I use this .reg to create a dword and assign its value?`

Tags: registry, dword

Coding is not normally something I need to do at my job (though I am interested in learning) but recently I have been asked to create a script that will make a registry change which resolves an issue some of our users are having.  Here is what I have:

REGEDIT4

REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Office\15.0\Common\Internet /v UseOnlineContent /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

I have it saved as a .reg file.  It runs, but it must not be right because when I check the registry afterward there is no sign of "UseOnlineContent."  All I need to do is create this dword (which doesn't already appear) and assign it a 0 value.  I'm sure this is kind of a dumb question, but any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is create the key manually in RegEdit.  Afterwards just click on your UseOnlineContent key and choose File -> Export.  The .reg file will be created for you automatically

Comment: That did it!  Thanks so much for your help.  Not only does this solve my issue, but I'm sure it will come in handy in the future.